# Unit test All the Actions Methods in Controller in .Net core visual studio 2017

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(DonorViewModel be, IFormFile pic)
{
    be.RegCampId = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Camp"]);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        DONOR entity = new DONOR(); 

        #region Insert Entities
        entity.Address = be.Address;
        entity.BarCode = be.BarCode;
        entity.BloodGroupId = be.BloodGroupId;
        entity.CityId = be.CityId;
        entity.CNIC = be.CNIC;
        entity.DOB = be.DOB;
        entity.Email = be.Email;
        entity.EmergencyContact = be.EmergencyContact;
        entity.FullName = be.FullName;
        entity.GenderId = be.GenderId;
        entity.HomeNo = be.HomeNo;
        entity.IsActive = true;
        entity.IsDeleted = false;
        entity.LastDonDate = be.LastDonDate;
        entity.MaritalStatus = be.MaritalStatus;
        entity.MobileNo = be.MobileNo;
        entity.Occupation = be.Occupation;
        entity.PreDonCount = be.PreDonCount;
        if (be.RegCampId != 0) { entity.RegCampId = be.RegCampId; entity.RegistrationTypeId = 3; }
        if (be.RegLocId != 0) { entity.RegLocId = be.RegLocId; entity.RegistrationTypeId = 2; }
        entity.SignPic = entity.SignPic;
        entity.WhatsApp = be.WhatsApp;
        entity.CreatedBy = (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId");
        entity.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        #endregion
        flag = await _donorContext.AddAsync(entity);

        if (pic == null || pic.Length <= 0)
            be.Pic = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", "Avatar.png").Replace(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "").Replace("\\", "/");

        if (pic != null && pic.Length > 0)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(new string[]
            {
                _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath,
                "Reservoir","Donor",entity.Id.ToString(),
                entity.Id + Path.GetExtension(pic.FileName)
            });
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                pic.CopyTo(stream);
            }
            path = path.Replace(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "").Replace("\\", "/");
            entity.Pic = path;

            entity.CreatedBy = entity.CreatedBy;
            entity.CreatedDateTime = entity.CreatedDateTime;
            entity.IsActive = true;
            entity.IsDeleted = false;
            await _donorContext.UpdateAsync(entity);
        }

        if (flag)
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "Donor is Added Successfully.";
            if (be.RegCampId != 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Create", "Donor", new { CampId = be.RegCampId });
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Create", "Donor");
            }
        }
    }
    ViewData["RegCampId"] = new SelectList(_context.BLOOD_CAMP, "Id", "City", be.RegCampId);
    ViewData["BloodGroupId"] = new SelectList(_bloodGroupContext.GetAll(), "Id", "Value", be.BloodGroupId);
    ViewData["CityId"] = new SelectList(_cityContext.GetAll(), "Id", "Name", be.CityId);
    ViewData["ScreenedBy"] = new SelectList(_context.EMPLOYEE, "Id", "FirstName", be.ScreenedBy);
    ViewData["GenderId"] = new SelectList(_genderContext.GetAll(), "Id", "Name", be.GenderId);
    ViewData["RegLocId"] = new SelectList(_locationService.GetAll(), "Id", "Name",be.RegLocId);

    return View(be);
}
```

This is My Create method In Controller How to unit test it using UnitTest.

```
using HMS_Presentation.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

//Unit Test code .

namespace HMS_UnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

            DonorController Controller = new DonorController();

            ViewResult result = Controller.Create() as ViewResult;

            Assert.AreEqual("",????);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my unit test class code how to use my controller object to check the actions and  test it . WHAT should i write the in the assert . I SEARCH it on internet but do not find any proper solution kindly check the code below and tell me what should i have to write in the assert . i am using visual studio 2017 and .NET CORE 2.0 AND adding a project of unit test in my solution.

The link i followed . 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/getting-started-with-unit-testing?view=vs-2017

Comment: You should seriously extract and abstract most of that code into service classes and test this classes and only do integration tests against the controllers. Its much easier to mock a single abstracted service and return test case specific data from the mock on the system under test (sut). P.S. your controller is async, also use async Stream API (`await pic.CopyToAsync(stream)`) otherwise there is no point in when your file access blocks the request thread

Answer (score 0):

In ASPNET Core 2.1 introduced feature called **Functional testing of MVC applications**.
To help streamline in-memory end-to-end testing of MVC applications using TestServer.
See below example

```
using Xunit;

namespace TestingMvc.Tests
{
    public class TestingMvcFunctionalTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationTestFixture<Startup>>
    {
        public TestingMvcFunctionalTests(WebApplicationTestFixture<Startup> fixture)
        {
            Client = fixture.CreateClient();
        }

        public HttpClient Client { get; }

        [Fact]
        public async Task GetHomePage()
        {
            // Arrange & Act
            var response = await Client.GetAsync("/");

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about functional testing of MVC Applications [click here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/05/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview1-functional-testing-of-mvc-applications/)

Comment: fwiw, that's integration testing :p